# How to convert MS SQL Server code into SAP HANA code?

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

Hello I am new in SAP HANA  and I have this T-SQL code:

```
`if(@IsBes='E')begin

               if((select top 1 U_bBesYontem from OHEM where empID=@EmpId)='O') begin

                     set @Bes=@Brut*(select top 1 U_bBesOran from OHEM where empID=@EmpId)/100

                  end

               if((select top 1 U_bBesYontem from OHEM where empID=@EmpId)='T') begin

                     set @Bes=(select top 1 U_bBesTutar from OHEM where empID=@EmpId)

                  end

         end`
```

And I am trying this code for SAP HANA

`IF (:IsBes = 'E') THEN 
          IF ((SELECT TOP 1 “U_bBesYontem" 
FROM 
     OHEM 
WHERE 
"empID" = :EmpId) = 'O') 
THEN 
Bes := :Brut * (SELECT TOP 1 "U_bBesOran" 
     FROM OHEM 
      WHERE 
         "empID" = :EmpId) / 100;
    END IF;
    IF ((SELECT TOP 1 "U_bBesYontem" 
 FROM OHEM 
 WHERE "empID" = :EmpId) = 'T') THEN 
         SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 "U_bBesTutar" 
        FROM OHEM 
        WHERE "empID" = :EmpId) INTO Bes 
 FROM DUMMY;
    END IF;
    END IF;`

And  tried lots of code variations but I always end up getting this error:

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported:
 Sub-query is not supported in a nested procedure call: 
 line 47 col 28 (at pos 2273)
```

I am confused so can somebody give any advise ?

Comment: Merhaba j.doe, do you want to put your code in AMDP ?

Answer (score 1):

Merhaba,

Could you please execute following SQLScript on a test database

```
do
begin

declare lv_EmpId int := 1;
declare lv_IsBes char(1) := 'E';
declare lv_Bes decimal(10,2); 
declare lv_Brut decimal(10,2) := 100;
declare lv_U_bBesYontem nvarchar(100);
declare lv_U_bBesOran int;
declare lv_U_bBesTutar int;

select top 1 
    U_bBesYontem, U_bBesOran, U_bBesTutar
into 
    "LV_U_BBESYONTEM", "LV_U_BBESORAN", "LV_U_BBESTUTAR"
from OHEM where EmpId = lv_EmpId;

if (:lv_IsBes = 'E') then

    if(:lv_U_bBesYontem = 'O') then
        lv_Bes = ( :lv_Brut * :lv_U_bBesOran ) /100;
    else
        if (:lv_U_bBesYontem = 'T') then
            lv_Bes = :lv_U_bBesTutar;
        end if;
    end if;

end if;

select :lv_Bes as "BES" from dummy;

end;
```

I had used following sample data and it seems to work quite fine, please modify the script according to your table and fields names, etc.

```
CREATE Column TABLE OHEM (
    empID int,
    U_bBesYontem varchar(10),
    U_bBesOran int,
    U_bBesTutar int
);
insert into OHEM select 1, 'O',5,1000 from dummy;
insert into OHEM select 2, 'O',10,500 from dummy;
insert into OHEM select 1, 'T',5,1000 from dummy;
insert into OHEM select 2, 'T',10,500 from dummy;
```

You can refer to variable declarations, value assignment, IF clause etc on [SQLScript](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/sap-hana-database-sqlscript-cursor-sample.aspx) at given sample document.